# Console application accepting restart call over localhost or web api

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, tcp

So I've been trying to allow someone to restart my program. Restarting means that I use

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(program);
Environment.Exit(0);
```

Now I've been trying to find a solution and thought it'd be possible to call either a localhost-port with `tcpListener` or through asp.net-web-api.

My question is if there are better solutions and if not where I can look up how to set up the better solution.

Comment: How are we going to know what's "better" for you in your particular situation? How did networking even come into a "restart my application" question? The only requirement you ever give us is that you want to be able to restart your application, and you think we'll be able to give you a "better" solution somehow.

Comment: So to further elaborate, I'm writing a program that will run on a server and I want to be able to restart that program through a web portal (java). So I decided that I would need some form of open point which will parse some information to my program which I can interprete into a restart call.

Comment: I would've just add an API to the existing portal to be consumed by the console app, so maybe it'll query the portal every minutes or so. That way your console app only need a web client instead of a web server.

Comment: True, that way around it'll be much easier. Thank you.